# Fill array with same data in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some data that returns me from the database, the problem is that not all the keys are associated, I should fill the missing keys with data to 0.

My array is by default is:

```
array:1 [▼
  9 => array:2 [▼
    4 => array:3 [▼
      "Orange" => array:3 [▼
        "price" => "600.00"
        "total" => "690.00"
      ]
      "Apple" => array:3 [▼
        "price" => "650.00"
        "total" => "870.00"
      ]
      "Banana" => array:3 [▼
        "price" => "50"
        "total" => "40"
      ]
    ]
    21 => array:1 [▼
      "Apple" => array:3 [▼
        "price" => "44"
        "total" => "33"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

The array should have the same structure but with data at 0

Result:

```
array:1 [▼
  9 => array:2 [▼
    4 => array:3 [▼
      "Orange" => array:2 [▼
        "price" => "600.00"
        "total" => "690.00"
      ]
      "Apple" => array:2 [▼
        "price" => "650.00"
        "total" => "870.00"
      ]
      "Banana" => array:2 [▼
        "price" => "50"
        "total" => "40"
      ]
    ]
    21 => array:3 [▼
      "Apple" => array:2 [▼
        "price" => "44"
        "total" => "33"
      ],
      "Orange" => array:2 [▼
        "price" => "0"
        "total" => "0"
      ],
      "Banana" => array:2 [▼
        "price" => "0"
        "total" => "0"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: well, you'll have to loop through the array and manually write some code that does that

Comment: Or rework the db query

Comment: you can look at functions like array_merge and set a variable with default keys and values.

Comment: I try with array_merge but is not the solution

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: @Alexd2 Then show us what you tried with array_merge... we would like to help you with your code, but we will not write it for you...

Answer (score 0):

The "for" below modify each array with adding any new value and also avoid duplicate values. Basically, it finds the differences and then merge that, setting the first array to clone each array.

```
$fruits = array (
    1 => array('Manzana', 'Naranja', 'Pera'),
    2 => array('Pera', 'Sandia'),
    3 => array('Manzana', 'Melocotones')
);
print_r($fruits);





for ($i = 1; $i <= count($fruits)-1; $i++) {
    $result = array_diff($fruits[1], $fruits[1+$i]);
    $merge = array_merge($fruits[1+$i], $result);
    $fruits[1+$i] = $merge;
    $fruits[1] = $merge;
}

print_r($fruits);
?>
```

[Here to see how run it!](https://repl.it/KqUi/3) 
https://repl.it/KqUi/3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always use the first element as boilerplate you can do something like this:

```
$boilerplate = reset($array);
array_walk_recursive($boilerplate, function (&$value) {
    $value = 0;
});

$array = array_map(function ($items) use ($boilerplate) {
    return array_merge($items, array_diff_key($boilerplate, $items));
}, $array);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ebf6cf4ec65416bf0470c4f15ea8a0e0b5c197c6).